# Parse Login Using Swift

Tags: ios, authentication, swift, parse-platform

I am creating a login page for my ios app using swift and Parse.  In my initial view controller, I have

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
if user != nil {
  println(user)
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(1, completion: nil)
} else {
  println("No Logged in user")
  var login: PFLogInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
  login.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton |        PFLogInFields.SignUpButton
  self.presentViewController(login, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

in my viewDidLoad method of the ViewController I want to go to after login. The login screen initially shows up, and I can then type in my information, but if I enter correct login information it doesn't go anywhere.  From that point, restarting the app allows me to be logged in.  I would like to be able to log in without having to restart the app, but do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to implement

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

which is called when a PFUser is logged in.

and in Swift

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser user: PFUser!) -> Void{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How could I do this in swift? I cannot seem to find this function

Comment: Do I put this in the view controller I want to go into after the login? I have entered this function into my first view controller. There are no errors and my app runs, but the login button still goes nowhere. Do I need to set something with delegate? The app crashes when I add in the line login.delegate = self

Comment: You are supposed to put this event in the initial view controller (as you did).If you put a breakpoint, does it stop into this event? This is supposed to be called on valid login and then `dismissViewControllerAnimated` dismisses the Log In View Controller (`presentViewController`)

Comment: My function now has println("Should logout") as the first line in the didLogInUser function.  This line is never displayed, so I do not believe this function is ever being called

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to change my class declaration to class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate so that the delegate line could properly set the delegate